# Hot Meta Posts not visible unless logged in

Tags: support, design, hot-questions, community-bulletin

I noticed that "Hot Meta Posts" doesn't show up unless I'm logged in.  Is this the intended behavior? If so, why?

Comment: Not much use of bringing those posts to their attention. They are not actionable. Also prevents that if things get too Hot it isn't made public to the millions of one-time visitors.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I think the vast majority of meta posts are not something a non-logged-in user would have any reason to be interested in

Comment: hehe.. well sometimes I do browse the site from a non-logged in browser.  would be great to avoid having to log in just to see that sidebar but no biggie

Comment: Hah, if that's the case, just assume all the meta posts are hot. ;)

Comment: @rene one that is currently shown in sidebar looks definitely worthy of any user attention, including those who aren't logged in - "Was there an update with a change of the line spacing?"

Comment: @gnat That wouldn't matter to a one-time user, though; the only reason they'd care about a change is if they knew how it was before.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica it doesn't look reasonable to assume logged out users one-time visitors. I think many people regularly use Stack Overflow by simply looking for the answers to their questions dumped in Google search without bothering to register. Heck I myself use it mostly this way and the fact that I am a registered user is sort of accidental, I would use it just the same if I wasn't registered

Comment: FWIW this is a network wide thing - I just checked two other sites, and these also had HMP disappear when browsing in logged-out mode